# using nodejs to automate bash interaction as if typing from a terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, child-process, spawn

I was trying to use "spawn" from "child_process" to talk to the "ssh" utility (Ubuntu 20, bash 5.0, node 19.6), but got the message "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal" (using "-t -t" made it bypass stdout and print directly to the terminal).
In this case I can probably just use a dedicated module, but I doubt that it is the only program that is fussy about where its input is coming from and I'd like to avoid this issue in the future.

Comment: Not an answer, but a comment: It can be dangerous in case you expose the shell as a REST API. It is safe if you allow only predefined commands, which this REST CLI I/O app does: https://github.com/peterthoeny/rest-cli-io

Answer (score 1):

per [ssh man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh), you should use `-T` (**disables** pseudo-tty allocation) instead of `-t` (**forces** pseudo-tty allocation).

this code spawns a new child process running the `ssh` command with the provided username and hostname, then listens to `stdout` and `stderr` streams:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

// define the SSH command to execute and its arguments
const ssh = spawn('ssh', ['-T', 'user@host']);

// handle SSH output events
ssh.stdout.on('data', (data) => console.log(`stdout: ${data}`));
ssh.stderr.on('data', (data) => console.error(`stderr: ${data}`));
ssh.on('close', (code) => console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`));
```

to interact with the SSH server, you can write to the `stdin` stream of the child process, for example, sending a `ls` command:

```js
ssh.stdin.write('ls\n');
```

to close the session you can either:

1. close the input stream to signal the end of input

```js
ssh.stdin.end();
```

2. send an `exit` command

```js
ssh.stdin.write('exit\n');
```

remember to replace the `user@host` accordingly, handle errors and exceptions appropriately.

Comment: That definitely gets rid of the errors for this particular case (ssh), but the string asking for (and accepting) the password still bypasses stdin/stdout completely and goes right to the keyboard.

Comment: i'm not sure how to redirect this password prompt to the nodejs' control, but probably you should consider to use pubkey authentication instead of password. you can use the option `-i privateKeyFile` to pass the custom path of your private key